# Can't make my dropdown menu items white

Tags: css

I can't get the color of my dropdown items white, someone knows how I can fix this?
My normal links needs to be black, the not active ones needs to be black, the active one needs to be white, the dropdown items needs to be white. I've got it all with that code except for the most up dropdown item.

Heres my css:

```
.menuitems{
        line-height: 240%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .menuitems ul {
        font-family: Arial, Verdana;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .menuitems ul li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
    .menuitems li ul {
        display: none;
    }
    .menuitems ul li a {
        height: 40px;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        border-left: 1px #D0D0D0 solid;
        padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
    }


    .menuitems li > ul li a
     {
       color:white;
     }
    .menuitems ul ul li{
        text-transform: none;
        border-bottom: 1px #ff5c38 solid;
        line-height: 380%;
    }
    .menuitems ul li:hover{
        background: url('images/menu-background1.png') repeat-x 0 0; 
    }

    .menuitems ul li a:hover {
        height:40px; 
        color: white;
        padding-left: 30px !important;
        padding-right: 30px !important;
    }
    .menuitems li:hover ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .menuitems li:hover li {
        float: none;
        font-size: 13px;
        background:  #fa3423;
    }
    .menuitems li:hover a { }
    .menuitems li:hover li a:hover {

    }
    /* What to do on active */
    .menuitems ul li.current_page_item { 
        background: url('images/menu-background1.png') repeat-x 0 0; 
    }
    .menuitems ul li.current_page_item a{ 
        color: white;
    }
    .menuitems li.current_page_parent a {
        color: white;
    }
    .menuitems li.current_page_parent {
        color: white;
        background: url('images/menu-background1.png') repeat-x 0 0; 
    }
    .menuitems li:hover ul:hover a:hover{
        color: white !important;
    }
    .menuitems ul li ul{
        color: white;
    }
```

I tried everything.. :(

Comment: Obviously not *everything* because it's not working. ;) Are you trying to make the background white or the text white? Also, if you could make a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) with your HTML and CSS demoing your problem, that'd be great. It's quite hard to figure out your problem with no HTML.

Comment: Yeah it would be good to see the html to understand which classes etc relate, a jsfiddle would be even better ;)

Comment: what @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas said ;)

Comment: I dont have any html because Im making this menu for WordPress,
The dropdown menu items font color needs to be white (all of them)

Comment: viewsource -> locate the menu relevant part of the html, post that

Comment: If you are using wordpress then you are using the wrong classes unless you have overridden their defaults generated by `wp_nav_menu()`.  By default wordpress gives the `ul` class `.menu`, `li`class is `menu-item` or `current-menu-item`

Comment: Thanks your right Iv found a nice tutorial http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-wordpress-navigation-menus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Castra, I assume you're talking about the text? If you want the text to always be white, you'll need to change `color: black;` in `.menuitems ul li a` to `color: white;`

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJWW6/) that shows it.

Comment: This is what i need yes, but my normal links are also white, and they need to be black: The not active ones needs to be black, the active one needs to be white, the dropdown items needs to be white also.

Iv got it all with that code except for the dropdown items